# How to get reusable url for a picture in firebase storage that has a known path?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I upload all my users profile photos in this path:

```
    const userUploadRef = ref(
      storage,
      `profilePhotos/${user.data?.uid}`
    );
```

I currently access the url like this:

```
  getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadUrl) => {
          if (user.data?.uid) {
            setDownloadURL(downloadUrl);
```

However, I just realized that even though the path is always going to be the same, each picture has a different url?

This causes massive issues - if I want to attach this user photo to something like comments, posts or any other content, I will have to make sure that the user profile image url is updated.

Surely there must be a way that I can reuse the same url since the path to the user profile photo is always going to be the same regardless?

Edit:

I have tried following this guide - https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens on how to remove the token and make my file public, but firebase keeps adding the token regardless.

```
        if (folder == "profilePhotos" && isThumbnail) {
          const [newFile]: any = file.makePublic();
          const [metadata] = newFile.getMetadata();
          const url = metadata.mediaLink;

          const userPublicRef = db.collection("usersPublic").doc(userId);
          const usersPrivateRef = db.collection("users").doc(userId);
```

Comment: Are you providing each picture with a unique ID? Are you planning to have duplicates of the photos? Are you assigning each photo an individual URL? Which Firebase documentation are you using to come up with the code?

Comment: I am using firebase v9 documentation, each picture will have the same uid as the firebase auth user i.e "user101" profile picture will be named "user101" and if this user updates this picture it will still have the same name, as mentioned in the title I want "user101" picture to always have the same URL.

Comment: Even if the user changes the photo many times, you want the URL to remain the same.  You want a static URL regardless of the photo the user uploads, correct?

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

If the photos are public, once you have uploaded them to Firebase storage, just do not pass the download token and that will achieve what you want (this is not a Firebase supported use).

The download of the URL will have the following format `firebasestorage.googleapis.com/XXX?alt=media&token=YYY` and the part that's changing is the token generated, you can remove this if the security rules allow anonymous access.

Here is a good [website](https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens) that can help you.

**1st answer edition:**

These are the rules that I used in Firebase storage:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true; 
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

By using these rules, the token is no longer needed and can be accessed by anyone, but you still need to remove the token from the URL manually

For example, here is the complete URL with the token:

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-firebase-application-92719.appspot.com/o/istockphoto-496152924-612x612.jpg?alt=media&token=960c993e-dc2b-483f-ae30-5c4eeb8c1e73`

You’ll need to delete after `&token` and you’ll get:

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-firebase-application-92719.appspot.com/o/istockphoto-496152924-612x612.jpg?alt=media`

Now I can access the picture without the need of the token of the test picture I created:

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-firebase-application-92719.appspot.com/o/istockphoto-496152924-612x612.jpg?alt=media`

**I would like to highlight that this is not a recommended security setting because now everything in the URL can be accessed by anyone.**

Comment: I never passed the token, firebase adds it automatically, I have tried following the guide in the website, but that didn't help. Do you still think its possible to access the file without token or as you mentioned firebase does not support it?

Comment: Did you check your security rules and set them to allow anonymous access? By setting the security rules to allow anonymous access, you remove the need of the token (this is the use that is not supported by Firebase). Firebase storage is primarily intended for authenticated access and not for public hosting.  I tested this in with an image I created in firebase (added as an edit to the answer).

Comment: @Ripas55: Was the information of any use?